# Difference between JSP1.2 and JSP2.0

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

What are the differences between JSP1.2 and JSP2.0?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the things mentioned in [JSP 2.0 - The New Deal](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/05/jsp.html), an often overlooked new JSP 2.0 feature is JSP tag files which can be a pretty cool way to create reusable components with JSP. That can be small tags just doing one thing used in many different JSP pages (like e.g. formatting a currency styled in a special way) or it can be used for general [template composition](http://fforw.de/post/Creating_JSP_Layouts_with_Page_Tags/).